# Can SQL Reporting Services use Lotus Notes as a datasource?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I would like to create a report from a project management system that has been created in Lotus Notes.  I have connected to ORACLE from SSRS before, can I connect to the Lotus Notes DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with a third-party adapter or driver.

Propoison has an adapter (Propoison Report Adapter) that connects to Lotus Notes and Domino environments.  Apparently they were [recently bought by Quest Software](http://www.quest.com/landing/?ID=1442), which I discovered by being redirected.  You'll have to call Quest to see if you'll have any development options now or going forward.

Alternatively it should be possible to connect to Notes using IBM's [NotesSQL ODBC driver](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/products/notesdomino/notessql/).